# How to access Django model when overriding Manager?

Tags: python, django, oop

I am overriding the "`get`" method in a shared Manager class, but I can't figure out How to grab the initial caller. For example when I run:

```
Animal.objects.get() -or- Plant.objects.get()
```

How can I have "`get`" know it's being called from Animal/Plant without passing in any parameters?

Here is my code for reference:

```
class CommonManager(models.Manager):
  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
     print ??? #how do I print Animal or Plant here?


class CommonModel(models.Model):
  objects = CommonManager()
  #stuff

class Animal(CommonModel):
  #stuff

class Plant(CommonModel):
  #stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, it seems to be `self.model`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, may I ask which part of the source you looked at? I'm new to Django and often have trouble with the docs.

Comment: It's mentioned at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager ("Another thing to note about this example is that Manager methods can access self.model to get the model class to which they’re attached."). It's easy to miss that, though; it's often a good strategy to drop into the Python debugger at do a dir(self) if you don't have another easy way to browse the code/superclasses.